# Manually installing CocoaPods Dependencies

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I am behind a corporate firewall that doesn't allow external source code to be directly downloaded from the Internet without appropriate control procedures. This means that we have to stand up our own Pub server and possibly our own CocoaPods private pod - not just the Spec file, but all of the source/binaries hosted across the Internet, and their transitive dependencies and so on.

Before building out such a tool, I want to see what it would take to install some CocoaPods dependencies manually. Is there any instructions available that might show me how to start with a Spec file and manually download third-party dependencies and configure my XCode to properly work with local copies of the libraries, frameworks and sdks?